# Can Intel RST in RAID5 configuration be used for Windows boot drive?

Tags: raid-5, intel-rst

I'm planning to build a new computer, motherboard will be based on X99 chipset. I'd like to set up 4 SSDs in RAID5 configuration, and use that volume for Windows boot.

Is it possible now? Can I configure RAID5 in Intel RST's BIOS?

I know it's doable with "real" RAID controllers, but last time I looked at Intel "pseudo-raid", their RAID5 support was Windows driver-only (but it was many years ago).

Comment: Along to this information, if you're planning to install system later that vista you will not have to do any special things to start install. http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-029979.htm

Comment: Intel RST RAID *is* driver only but you have always been able to boot from it.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: RAID1, RAID0 and RAID10: sure, always. RAID5? Not so, I remember not being able to create or change RAID5 volumes in RST option ROM, and not being able to boot from RST RAID5. This was many years ago, though.

Comment: @haimg: I admit I've not checked on my own board, but Intel's documentation from 2011 *implies* it works with RAID-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my Windows 7 booting from RST RAID 5 for a couple years. Eventually bought a non-RAID SSD and migrated over, using the 4-HDD RAID 5 for bulk storage. You just need to load the RAID driver at install time. However, Windows 8 and 10 should not need the driver, and certain 7 media may not either. Still, could be handy to drop the driver on your Windows installer USB.

However, please note that RAID-5 is sub-optimal for SSDs because of all the writing (parity bits), and that Intel RAID is not true hardware RAID. This means RAID overhead (and 5 has much more than 10) taking up CPU resources when you stress the disks. You should be able to do it though.